# Wedge volume of sphere problem

Tags: calculus, geometry

The [Clare College bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Cambridge_legends#Clare_College_bridge) at Cambridge is decorated with 14 stone spheres, but one of it missed a wedge. I took a photo to estimate the volume of the missing part  of the sphere. I am not confident with my calculations, therefore I post my exercise hoping anyone would be so kind to give me their opinion.

[image]

If we put the sphere in cartesian axes, with the center of the sphere at x=y=0 point. The missing section is on the quadrant that starts on the point (0.4, 0.3). I tried to calculate the integral of the corresponding [circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

The circular segment is calculated as sector area minus triangle area, I used the sector area formula $n \pi r^2 /360$ (n = angle grades).

$n= cos^-1(0.4/y)=cos^-1(0.4/\sqrt(1-x^2)) = 2\alpha$ (0.4 because triangle is always 0.4 hight) and $r^2=1-x^2$

Therefore, I calculated the sector area depending of x like $(\pi (1-x^2) cos^-1(0.4/\sqrt(1-x^2))/180$ and I calculated a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse = r = y, h = 0.4 and the other cathetus is $p = \sqrt(1-x-0.4^2) = \sqrt(0.84-x^2)$.

I attach a picture to complement the explanation.

[image]
Continuing:

The area of circular segment could be calculate from x as:

$$(1/180)*Pi(1-x^2)*arccos(.4/sqrt(1-x^2))-.4*sqrt(0.84-x^2)$$

And integrate it from $x=0.3$ to $x=\sqrt(0.84)$ =y=0.4.

$\int_\sqrt{0.84}^{0.3}((\frac{1}{180})*\pi(1-x^2)*arccos(\frac{0.4}{\sqrt(1-x^2)})-0.4*\sqrt(0.84-x^2)dx$

[image]

The numerical result is 0.1492 and the volume of sphere of r= 1 is $4/3 \pi r^3 = 4.1887$, and the proportion of sphere is $\frac{4.1887-0.1492}{4.1884} = 0.964$.

Seems strange to me  that only 4% of stone ball is missing.